# Setting color of area in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm creating a chart with matplotlib, here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0), facecolor='#131722')

Colors = [['#0400ff', '#FF0000'], ['#09ff00', '#ff8c00']]

for x in List:

    Index = List.index(x)

    rate_buy = []
    total_buy = []

    for y in x['data']['bids']:
        rate_buy.append(y[0])
        total_buy.append(y[1])

    rBuys = pd.DataFrame({'buy': rate_buy})
    tBuys = pd.DataFrame({'total': total_buy})

    ax1.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, color=Colors[Index][0], linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.8)
    ax1.fill_between(rBuys.buy, 0, tBuys.total, facecolor=Colors[Index][0], alpha=1)
```

And here is the output:
[image]

The problem with the current output is that the colors of the two areas are "merging": basically the area BELOW the blue line should be blue, but instead it's green. How can i set it to be blue, for example, like in my example?

Example `List` data:

```
[[9665, 0.07062500000000001], [9666, 0.943708], [9667, 5.683787000000001], [9668, 9.802289], [9669, 11.763305], [9670, 14.286004], [9671, 16.180122], [9672, 23.316723000000003], [9673, 30.915156000000003], [9674, 33.44226200000001], [9675, 36.14526200000001], [9676, 45.76024100000001], [9677, 51.85294700000001], [9678, 58.79529300000001], [9679, 59.05322900000001], [9680, 60.27704500000001], [9681, 60.743885000000006], [9682, 66.75103700000001], [9683, 71.86412600000001], [9684, 73.659636], [9685, 78.08502800000001], [9686, 78.19614200000001], [9687, 79.98396400000001], [9688, 90.55855800000002]]
```

Comment: What's in your variable `List`?  Maybe you can switch the order of drawing (e.g. `for x in List[::-1]:`)?

Comment: I think the problem is not with the data, the problem is with MPL. The variable List is the data i'm charting

Comment: If you don't clarify, e.g. with a toy example, what the variable `List` contains, it is hard to answer your question. As you do a `fill_between` from 0 to your curve, everything will be drawn upon each other, and only the last will be visible. If by coincidence the last curve is the highest, it's `fill_between` will erase all the other. Did you really try `for x in List[::-1]` ? Did you note the difference???

Comment: @JohanC I added a sample of my List data. My bad for not understanding, i think the issue is what you mean: it depends on the height of the curve. I tried with [::1] but the output was the same; i'm going to try what was suggested in the answer, but i think i understood what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the hint of @JohanC is correct, you are plotting in the wrong order and overlay your previous plots with new ones.

I tried to recreate a small example where `total_buy1` > `total_buy0`, so in order to get the desired result you first have to plot `total_buy1`
and then `total_buy0`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Colors = [['#0400ff', '#FF0000'],
          ['#09ff00', '#ff8c00']]

n = 100
rate_buy = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)
total_buy0 = np.linspace(0, 300, n)[::-1] + np.random.normal(scale=10, size=n)
total_buy1 = np.linspace(0, 600, n)[::-1] + np.random.normal(scale=10, size=n)

ax.plot(rate_buy, total_buy1, color=Colors[1][1], linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.8)
ax.fill_between(rate_buy, 0, total_buy1, facecolor=Colors[1][0], alpha=1)

ax.plot(rate_buy, total_buy0, color=Colors[0][1], linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.8)
ax.fill_between(rate_buy, 0, total_buy0, facecolor=Colors[0][0], alpha=1)
```

[image]

I noticed that you use `Colors[Index][0]` for both plotting calls, so the line and the area will not have different colors.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that i need to plot them according to the size of the data. If i plot the smallest before the bigger one, i'll get the wrong output. I need to plot from the biggest to the smallest, as you and @JohanC suggested